# Layer files not drawing properly in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, layer-file, windows-10

I have a co-worker who had his windows user credentials changed after coming on full time. After this change we noticed an issue with a series of layerfiles not drawing properly when brought into ArcMap.

This only seems to be an issue for the layer files that are referencing ArcGIS Server connections. For example, we have a layerfile that references imagery from the Virginia (VGIN) server and when he brings this in the layer file has no error, it is just completely empty.

No one else in my organization has this issue, only my one co-worker. This makes me believe that it is related to his Windows user credentials being changed. His "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\ESRI" folder has been updated with his new user name and I am not able to find any trace of the old user name being referenced anywhere.

Is anyone able to point me in the direction to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does your enterprise database use Windows credentials or database credentials? When you say ArcGIS Server are you consuming the layers as a web service (basemap?) or as a database connection? If it's a database connection are you using versioning? What database engine is it?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The layers we are using are ArcGIS map services as a basemap. The database connections are no issue.

Comment: You may need to flush the cache, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/managing-your-local-display-cache.htm might help. Can you ensure that the user has write permission to all files in %Userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\ESRI and that the system variables %Userprofile% and %AppData% point to the updated credentials https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: We tried clearing the cache earlier today and that didn't seem to help. I did read into resetting the ArcMap profile.... https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile Any thoughts on doing this?

Comment: Can the user move to a different workstation, login and check if the layers appear correctly? If so it's a local problem, if not it's an ArcGIS server problem. To fix a local problem try the linked post in your comment and if no joy there you might need to uninstall/reinstall ArcGIS desktop.

Comment: Are the database connections configured to use "Operating system authentication" or "Database authentication"? (Right click the layer, select "Properties" then the "Source" tab, and look at the "Authentication Type" item).  If it is using OS authentication, you may need to get an AD admin or DBA to check the Roles/Groups in AD/database to make sure the new username has the right privileges.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.