# Add Layer Failed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layer-file, windows-10, image-service

I am having an issue after my IT department changed my user login profile info. Everything works fine except for a bunch of layer files we use that reference imagery services. Everytime I try to bring in the layer files I get the following error message.

[image]

The blue mark covers the user name, which is still pointing to the old user profile and not the newly created user credentials. I went through the ArcMap options and confirmed that the map cache is pointing to the newly created profile and not the old one. I also tried resetting my ArcGIS application profile by renaming the %APPDATA%\ESRI folder to force ArcMap to create new profile data... this did not work either.

I really cant seem to figure out what the issue is.

Anyone have any suggestions?

I am running ArcMap 10.6.1

Everyone in my department is running the same version of ArcMap and nobody seems to have the same issue. So, it does not seem like a version issue like the error message states.

Comment: Please always provide full error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: This looks like it may be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/328317/115

Comment: I think it is time for you to get your IT people to talk to Esri's support people.

Comment: This is a separate issue from the previous question. The other question was relating to inaccessible group layer properties. That issue was addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem as you are having. It was as easy as clearing the image cache.
Customise > ArcMap Options > Display Cache > Clear Cache

In the last Windows upgrade the month it renamed your user name in AppData to XXXXX.000 which hides the added layer files from ESRI.